# Saving value of arrays with same value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want save array who the biggest value and the biggest with same value like this.

```
array:5 [▼
 24 => 0.37647133759351
 20 => 0.37647133759351
 "20,24" => 0.22588280255611
 34 => 0.011763621730179
 "26,34" => 0.0094108973841436
]
```

Because `24` and `20` is the biggest and has same value, then save they are to database with this way.

```
$hasilInsert = array();
    foreach ($sameValue as $key => $value) {
      $hasilInsert = array(
        'id_wi' => $wisatawan->id,
        'hasil' => $value['key'],
        'nilai' => $value['value']
        );
      $xy = HasilWisataTemp::insert($hasilInsert);
    }
```

How to I handle this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max()` to locate the highest value, then `array_keys()` to pick out the keys with that value, then `array_flip()` and `array_intersect_key()` to help with returning the array in the previous structure.

Therefore...

```
$result = array_intersect_key( $array, array_flip( array_keys( $array, max( $array ) ) ) );
```

will give you this result for you to iterate over and insert into the database...

```
Array
(
    [24] => 0.37647133759351
    [20] => 0.37647133759351
)
```

---

If you want to get the max of *only duplicate entries*, then use this first...

```
$duplicates = array_intersect( $array, array_diff_assoc( $array, array_unique( $array ) ) );
```

before calling...

```
$result = array_intersect_key( $duplicates, array_flip( array_keys( $duplicates, max( $duplicates ) ) ) );
```